# How to get data from LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

Here is an example output that I am looking for, for my program.

**Example Output**

> On each line enter a stadium name and the game revenue
>
> Enter done when you are finished
>
> Giants 1000
>
> Foxboro 500
>
> Giants 1500
>
> done
>
> Enter the name of a stadium to get the total revenue for:
>
> Giants
>
> The total revenue is 2500.00

I got everything working but the total revenue at the end. I'm not sure how to go into my linkedlist and grab the game revenue and display it.. This is my code right now, and what I have been messing with...

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LinkedLists {

    private final Scanner keyboard;



    private final LinkedList<String> stadiumNames;
    private final LinkedList<Integer> gameRevenue;


    public LinkedLists() {
        this.keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.stadiumNames = new LinkedList<String>();
        this.gameRevenue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    public void addData(String stadium, int revenue){
        stadiumNames.add(stadium);
        gameRevenue.add(revenue);
    }

    public void loadDataFromUser() {
        System.out.println("On each line enter the stadium name and game revenue.");
        System.out.println("Enter done when you are finished.");

        boolean done = false;
        while(!done) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the stadium:");
            String stadium = keyboard.next();
            if (stadium.equals("done")) {
                done = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Enter game revenue: ");
                addData(stadium, keyboard.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }

    // return -1 if not found
    public int getIndexForName(String name) {

        if(stadiumNames.contains(name)){
            System.out.println("The total revenue is: " +gameRevenue.get(0));
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return -1;

    }


    public void showInfoForName(String name) {
        int index = getIndexForName(name);
        if (index==-1) {
            System.out.println("There is no stadium named " + name);
        } else {

        }
    }

    public void showInfoForName() {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the stadium to get the total revenue for it.");
        showInfoForName(keyboard.next());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedLists pgm = new LinkedLists();
        pgm.loadDataFromUser();
        pgm.showInfoForName();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use linked lists?

Comment: ^ depended haha If he just wants a total revenue then it can be easily obtained by iterate through the linkedlist and sum up the revenue lol Though, I doubt he wanted something like that

Comment: Well if you could explain how to get the total using hash map or iterate then that would help. Just learning how to get the total revenue in my program

Comment: @MattMcCarthy How have you tried to iterate over the list and sum the values? There's a Java language construct to support easy iteration over lists...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
public int getIndexForName(String name) {
    if (stadiumNames.contains(name)) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < stadiumNames.size() ; i++)
            if (stadiumNames.get(i).equals(name))
                total += gameRevenue.get(i);
        System.out.println("The total revenue is: " + total);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

There are better ways of doing this though. I would perhaps use a `Map` that maps each stadium name to its total revenue. You could update this map in the `addData` method.

Comment: Heh well I'm glad I could help. Don't forget to accept ;D Also, you might wanna tag your question as homework if that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

using hash map is much cleaner, plus you can save the total on the side and not calculate it:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * User: user
 * Date: 09/09/2012
 */
public class Blah {

    private Scanner keyboard;
    private Map<String, Integer> stadiumRevenues;
    private Integer total = 0;

    public Blah() {
        this.keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.stadiumRevenues = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public void addData(String stadium, int revenue){
        stadiumRevenues.put(stadium, revenue);
        total += revenue;
    }

    public void loadDataFromUser() {
        System.out.println("On each line enter the stadium name and game revenue.");
        System.out.println("Enter done when you are finished.");

        boolean done = false;
        while(!done) {
            System.out.print("Enter the name of the stadium:");
            String stadium = keyboard.next();
            if (stadium.equals("done")) {
                done = true;
            } else {
                System.out.print("Enter game revenue: ");
                addData(stadium, keyboard.nextInt());
            }
        }
    }

    public int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    // return -1 if not found
    public int getIndexForName(String name) {

        Integer rev = stadiumRevenues.get(name);

        if(rev != null){
            System.out.println("The total revenue is: " +rev);
            System.exit(0);
        }

        return -1;

    }

    public void showInfoForName(String name) {

        Integer rev = stadiumRevenues.get(name);

        if (rev == null) {
            System.out.println("There is no stadium named " + name);
        } else {

        }
    }

    public void showInfoForName() {
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the stadium to get the total revenue for it.");
        showInfoForName(keyboard.next());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Blah pgm = new Blah();
        pgm.loadDataFromUser();
        pgm.showInfoForName();
    }


}
```